# C; headers and code

Tags: c, header

I'm beginner in C programming, so I have question about basic stuff.
 
When I work with non-standard packages and include their headers into my projects, I'm always getting "undefined reference to function" errors. I see that header files don't contain  internal code of functions, and I'm guessing that I need to link headers with the code somehow. So my question is, should I search for some libraries like dlls, which contain the functions, or should I look for C source files, and in any case, how I'm gonna link them with headers and put them all together to work in my project? I'm using CodeBlocks + MinGW.

Comment: Care to give an example of some packages you've included? Like `#include <math.h>` or something less common?

Comment: Include the header files in the C code. Link to the appropriate library. Most stuff tell you the header and the appropriate library in the documentation.

Comment: What extensions those libraries have? If it is .dll, I don't see any dll file in this particular package.

Comment: @HeikoHerlich - does it have documentation?

Comment: @HeikoHerlich Which library you are using?

Comment: link for package I downloaded:http://www.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v19_20111121.tgz. I included portaudio.h into my program.

Comment: There's no dlls in this package, so is something missing?

Comment: On the tutorial page there are directions on compiling for different platforms, have you looked at this page? http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html

Comment: You need to compile the thing. It is just source code. Just read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build (actually link with the library) your executable against the external library you are using which you can specify using the `-L path to lib` `gcc` flag.

e.g

```
gcc -L path_to_lib -llib prog.c -o executable
```

you can use `locate lib_name` to know the path of the library.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you have a header file in C you will have the header file Example:

> ```
> //func.h
> int myfunc(int x);
> ```

then you will have a source file

> Blockquote

```
//func.c
#include "func.h"
int myfunc(int x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Then your source file that has main()

```
//main.c
#include "func.h"
int main(){
    int x = 2;
    x = myfunc(x);
    return x;
}
```

in your ide you include main.c and func.c in your source files. And include func.h in your header files.

I don't use code block, but basically any ide would work this way.